# Как задать Margin для элементов через код, через стили?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Как создать стиль в коде и проставить одинаковые значения всем элементам, чтобы выравнять их в StackPanele?

```
public void myStackPanel()
{
    labelAssociacion.Margin = new Thickness(315, -1735, 15, 15);
    textAssociacion.Margin = new Thickness(-322, -3365, 15, 150);
    labelField.Margin = new Thickness(315, -3115, 15, 15);
    cbc.Margin = new Thickness(-322, -3015, 15, 15);
    lll2.Margin = new Thickness(315, -2232, 15, 15);
    bh1.Margin = new Thickness(325, -2980, 0, 0);
    addArticleEditor.Margin = new Thickness(370, -2980, 0, 0);
    delArticleEditor.Margin = new Thickness(420, -2980, 0, 0);
    editArticle.Margin = new Thickness(470, -2980, 0, 0);
    clearArticle.Margin = new Thickness(520, -2980, 0, 0);
    moveFirstArticle.Margin = new Thickness(570, -2980, 0, 0);
    movePreviousArticle.Margin = new Thickness(620, -2980, 0, 0);
    moveNextArticle.Margin = new Thickness(670, -2980, 0, 0);
    moveLastArticle.Margin = new Thickness(720, -2980, 0, 0);
    previewEditArticle.Margin = new Thickness(770, -2980, 0, 0);
    buttonNextConstructRelations.Margin = new Thickness(820, -2980, 0, 0);
    ll2.Margin = new Thickness(315, -2212, 15, 15);
    ll2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    p1.Margin = new Thickness(382, -3495, 15, 150)

}
```

Comment: Вы не должны пользоваться растановкой маргинов вручную, это не WinForms. Воспользуйтесь layout manager'ом.

Answer (score 1):

В WPF есть возможность располагать элементы не задавая Margin как в WindowsForms

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"/>
    </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

Основной плюс подобного задания - при изменении размеров окна автоматически происходит изменение размеров всех элементов, т.е. не надо задавать заново размеры

Width = "50*" - подгоняется пропорционально окну

Width = "35" - константно 35

Width = "auto" - автоматический размер

Свойство Column задает номер колонки, свойство ColumnSpan - на сколько колон располагается объект

Еще есть Grid.ColumnDefinition - его тоже используют для той же цели